# Why run Docker under Vagrant?

Tags: docker, vagrant, macos-sierra

I've read multiple articles how to do this, but I can't figure out what the benefits are under macOS.

From my point of view, you can run Docker natively on macOS using Docker Community Edition (boot2docker+Kitematic). What does it's give me for running from Vagrant, mobility?

Comment: For what we experience it is not really something that gives benefits other then mimic a server better (cpu, memory etc.) Only for Windows users, vagrant is usefull to run Docker (but that is also not true anymore since Docker Toolbox

Comment: Are you talking about using the Docker provider for Vagrant or spinning up Vagrant and then using Docker inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My standard day to day development work is carried out in Docker For Mac/Windows as they cover about 95% of what I need to do with Docker. Since they replaced Docker Toolbox/boot2docker and made the integration to the OS pretty seamless I have found very few reasons to move over to another virtual machine. The two main reasons I see for [using Vagrant](https://github.com/deployable/docker-debianvm) or standalone VM's now are for VM customisation and clustering.

### VM Customisation

The virtual machines supplied by Docker Toolbox, Docker for Mac/Windows are pre packaged cut down Linux distros ([TinyCore](http://www.tinycorelinux.net/) and [Alpine](https://www.alpinelinux.org/)) that are largely ephemeral, except for the Docker configuration so you don't get much say in how they work.

#### Networking

I deal with a number of custom network configurations that just aren't possible in the pre packaged VM's, largely around having containers connected to routable networks rather than using mapped ports.

#### Version Control

Occasionally you need to replicate server environments that run old versions of the Docker daemon, or RHEL servers using devicemapper. A VM let's you choose the packages to install.

### Clustering

Building a swarm, or branching out into [Mesosphere](https://mesosphere.com/)/[Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) will require multiple VM's. I tend to find these easier to manage and build with Vagrant rather than Docker Machine, and again they require custom config inside the VM.