# More swap space for Docker on Mac OSX Yosemite

Tags: oracle, macos, docker

I am trying to add more swap space in docker in order to avoid this error installing oracle database:

> This system does not meet the minimum requirements for swap space. 
>   Based on the amount of physical memory available on the system, Oracle
>   Database 11g Express Edition requires 2048 MB of swap space. This
>   system has 1023 MB of swap space.  Configure more swap space on the
>   system and retry the installation.

I am following the instructions commented here:

https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-for-mac-configure-swap-space/20656/2
but when I execute mkswap I get "command not found":

```
mkswap /var/swap.file
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you running this inside of your container, or on your mac?

Comment: Running on my mac

Comment: I'm assuming that is meant to be run inside your linux container, rahter than on the mac. Can you run it inside the container? Also what docker image are you using? This might be a good reference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Docker for Mac runs an Alpine Linux VM... the command needs to be run there

Answer (score 0):

Docker for Mac runs an Alpine Linux VM to host containers.

This is a prebuilt boot image that is designed for ease of use, and also updates over time so it can be hard to customise some times as most config is reset when you reboot it.

In this case you can persist a swap file change, but config like this has the possibility of changing between versions without notice. You might be better off running a [custom VM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46664628/1318694) for this so your swap configuration hangs around.

#### Docker for Mac 17.06.0

Swap is controlled by the `do_swapfile` function in the `/etc/init.d/automount` init script in the VM. If the swap file exists, it will be used as is. As the swap file is stored in `/var` it is persisted across reboots and can be manually customised.

Attach to the VM's tty from your mac with `screen` (`brew install screen` if you don't have it)

```
screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty
```

Then in the VM, replace the existing swap file with a new one of the required size and reboot the box. The size of the file is the block size `bs` * `count`.

```
 swapoff -a
 dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/spool/swap bs=1k count=2097152
 chmod 600 /var/spool/swap
 mkswap /var/spool/swap
 reboot
```

When the VM has rebooted, you should be able to connect again and see the new size of the VM's `Swap` space with `free`.

```
 $ screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty
 / # free
                  total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
     Mem:       3526164     389952    3136212     165956      20968     208160
     -/+ buffers/cache:     160824    3365340
     Swap:      2097148          0    2097148
```